# Kohana 2 jQtouch Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, kohana, jqtouch

Trying to load some data from mysql into the next screen using jQtouch. What is the correct way of doing this. Right now I just have a jquery click event on the  tag for the next page which really is just a div on the same page. The jquery looks like this.

`$.post("/mobile/getCities", {}, function(data){ loadURL($(this).attr('href'), "#findyourhome"); });`

this call hits a controller and pulls the data. Once I have the data I am setting it to a view-variable inside the controller.  I think the issue was the fact that the index function gets hit again this way so the view variable never properly gets set.

Answer (score 0):

Although not really an answer?
Are you just starting out?

In that case might I suggest taking a look at jQuery Mobile...

http://jquerymobile.com/

Seems like jQuery Mobile is making a strong start.

http://www.google.com/trends?q=jquery+mobile%2C+jqtouch&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=0

However if your work is tied to jQtouch... I have no clue...

You could also maybe try sencha tocuh. They tried selling it but now it's more or less free I think.

http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/

Not to sound pessimistic, I just don't see too much momentum from the jQtouch community lately.